# Creating an ecommerce store with drupal with external marketplace products

Tags: ecommerce, drupal

I would like to create a website to display selected products from eBay, Amazon, or other marketplaces. I'd like to display these products in a real shop template. Instead of people buying them on my site, however, I'd like to redirect them to the appropriate marketplace.

I've tried using the [Drupal Commerce module](https://drupal.org/project/commerce), but it's hard to avoid using the inside payment system. I've also tried an Amazon plugin, but there was no way to add other products.

Is there a store plugin which offers the ability to create products with:

- a description,
- a price, and
- a link to the store where the product is?

This plugin would also be able to filter products by category, price, etc.

As an example, WordPress has [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/), which offers the ability to add products from other stores. However, I'd prefer to use Drupal (and avoid using WordPress).

**Note**: An automatic import might be very usefull.

Comment: So you don’t need a cart, a list of orders, shipping/payment forms, etc.? -- The links would lead to the external sites, and when users buys something there, they wouldn’t be redirected back to your site, correct? -- And you are fine with creating the products manually, so an automatic import is not required?

Comment: An automatic import might be very usefull.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don’t need a shopping module at all.

You could build such a site by using general Drupal modules only, without having to code a single line yourself.

1. Create a vocabulary "Categories".
2. Create a content type "Product".

   1. Use the "Title" field for the product name, and the "Body" field for the product description.
   2. Add a term field "Category", using the "Categories" vocabulary.
   3. Add a "Price" field, for example with the [**Currency** module](https://drupal.org/project/currency).
   4. Add a "Link" field, for example with the [**Link** module](https://drupal.org/project/link).
3. Use the [**Views** module](https://drupal.org/project/Views) to create product lists with filters.
4. You are done.

If you want to import products from those external shops (instead of having to add the products manually), this would require some more work and possibly also coding. You could use the [**Feeds** module](https://drupal.org/project/feeds). If those sites don’t offer their data in a supported format, have a look at an  [example for a scraper module](https://drupal.org/project/example_web_scraper).